# Is the new Android Calendar API in ICS backward compatible?

Tags: android, eclipse, calendar

I am learning Android and have been working on an application that will need to read and write to the user's calendar.  I'm very much aware that there was no public API until Android 4.0 (ICS).  But, there was 'calendar functionality' in earlier versions of Android.

My question is; now that there is an official public API, will it work only with Android 4.0 and future releases or is it now possible to access calendars on phones that run earlier versions of Android?  Can the new API be included as a separate library when targeting earlier versions of Android? [I'm working in Eclipse] If so how would this be done?

I'd like to avoid using the old non-public approaches that don't conform to the official released calendar API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will it work only with Android 4.0 and future releases or is it now possible to access calendars on phones that run earlier versions of Android?

It only exists on Android 4.0+.

> Can the new API be included as a separate library when targeting earlier versions of Android?

No, given your following limitation:

> I'd like to avoid using the old non-public approaches that don't conform to the official released calendar API.

It is conceivable -- though far from certain -- that either:

- `CalendarContract` happens to simply *be* the "old non-public approach", granted official status, or
- One could take the source code to `CalendarContract` and, for at least a subset of the capabilities, modify it to work with older editions of the private APIs

The latter would probably work something like ActionBarSherlock, where it passes the request along to the native implementation on Android 4.0+ and uses its own implementation on earlier versions of Android.

In either case, there is still the possibility that vendors modified the Calendar app and therefore `CalendarContract` will not be completely compatible. In the second scenario I outline, whoever maintains this compatibility library could perhaps implement device-specific workarounds for such cases.

Comment: I'm using Joda Time. Check out joda.org. The calendars and time routines work with apps starting at 1.5. The release I've been using does give a warning that can't be fixed, but doesn't cause any problems with the Android code. It took me about a day to install the jars files. I'm still learing all the stuff it can do.

Comment: @HowardHodson: The OP is not referring to date management, but calendars (e.g., Google Calendar).

Comment: Thanks Mark, this IS helpful in that it re-states the question a bit more clearly.  I'd like to be able to use the new public CalendarContract (or something that wraps it) with pre-ICS versions of Android (specifically 2.x) without having to maintain two separate apks.  Indeed, something like ActionBarSherlock designed for the calendar API is likely what I'm looking for. Good lead, thanks. I'm early on the learning curve for Android coding and would likely not be up to building such a wrapper myself until I'm further along.